# How can I verify the authenticity of a ledger Nano s hardware wallet?

Tags: hardware-wallet, firmware

If I buy a Ledger Nano s hardware wallet online from Taobao in China is there any way I can verify it's authenticity? Is there a way to test the firmware etc to make sure it hasn't been tampered with?

Answer (score 4):

Found this just after asking the question.

https://blog.ledger.co/how-to-protect-hardware-wallets-against-tampering-cad35cb72c1